# Exception after ClickOnce Deployment AppData\Local\Temp FileNotFoundException

Tags: clickonce, filenotfoundexception, artemis

After Click once installs I get this exception.  Most users in the system do not get this error and the application runs fine.  There are a select few users that run into this error.  It does not matter what machine they install on.

I have a feeling it is a group policy issue.  Any help is appreciated.

Details: Could not find file `'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\Q4NW1PKL.OT1\A740DGRA.6EL\MyHelperEXEFile.exe'.`

Stack Trace:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 
          rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions   options, 
          SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.GetTransformedStream(String filePath,
         CMS_HASH_TRANSFORM transform)
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.GenerateDigestValue(String filePath,
         CMS_HASH_DIGESTMETHOD digestMethod, CMS_HASH_TRANSFORM transform)
at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentVerifier.VerifyFileHash(String filePath, 
         Hash hash)
```

### Update - Solved

After investigating the Application Events in event viewer it turns out McAfee was deleting this file while click once was doing the install. Claiming it had a virus. Artemis Trojan

community.mcafee.com/thread/2016

Once McAfee was disabled I was able to complete the installation.

Comment: Hi,
Just a hunch, but is the installation File path too long because of the Usernames?

Comment: No, it is a short username.  There are other users with longer usernames and they can install and run the click once application.

Comment: After investigating the Application Events in event viewer it turns out McAfee was deleting this file while click once was doing the install.  Claiming it had a virus. Artemis Trojan

https://community.mcafee.com/thread/2016

Once McAfee was disabled I was able to complete the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the Application Events in event viewer it turns out McAfee was deleting this file while click once was doing the install.  Claiming it had a virus. Artemis Trojan

https://community.mcafee.com/thread/2016

Once McAfee was disabled I was able to complete the installation.